# looking for virtual machine download

Tags: virtual-machine

I want to install a virtual machine in my laptop to learn PL SQL , MS Sql, BIDS.
When i google for a free virtual machine, I get windows virtual PC but that is not available in Microsoft site now.

Answer (score -1):

Closing this post !!

After doing some googling, found Oracle VM used for their Network Developer Day.

Going with this one for the time being as this was also used in my previuos company.

[Oracle Virtual Box](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html)

Comment: But you didn't actually do anything except write that you're closing?